# Place divs on the same level

Tags: html, css

Im wondering how to make both divs aligned? Can't get it up or down to level them out. [This.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwpjE.png)

```css
.crypto-card .value-label{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: .8rem;
}
 .crypto-card .value{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  right: -60px;
  top: 4px;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="value">Ethereum classic</div>
        <div class="value-label"><span class="title">15.29 TH/s</span></div>
```

}

Comment: I dont understand correctly. You want to have it like in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwpjE.png)?

Comment: Where is your div `crypto-card`, did you forget something ?

Comment: add a `display:inline-block;' both the `.value` and the `.value-label`, `div` has a default `block`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```css
.crypto-card {
    width: 20rem;
    height: 5rem;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.crypto-value-label {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    right: 10%;
}

.crypto-image {
    height: 1rem;
    padding: 0 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="crypto-card">
    <img class="crypto-image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Ethereum_logo_translucent.svg"/>
    <div class="crypto-name">
        Ethereum classic
    </div>
    <div class="crypto-value-label">
        <span class="title">15.29 TH/s</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can change the positioning of the label by adjusting

```
bottom: 10%;
right: 10%;
```

of the '.crypto-value-label' class.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to set the crypto-card div’s display to flex and then set the align-self property of the div that you wanna move down to flex-end.

```css
.crypto-card{
   height:100px;
   border:2px solid green;
   width:100%;
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-around;
 }
 

.crypto-card .value-label{
  align-self:flex-end;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: .8rem;
}
.crypto-card .value{
 
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 100;
   
}
```

```html
<div class= "crypto-card">
    <div class="value">Ethereum classic</div>
    <div class="value-label">
       <span class="title">15.29 TH/s</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this close to what you're trying to accomplish?

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 400px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.value {
  flex: 1;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 30px 0;
}

.value-label {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: .8rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="value">Ethereum classic</div>
  <div class="value-label"><span class="title">15.29 TH/s</span></div>
<div/>
```

Answer (score 0):

can do it with css grid also, you just have to say you want a grid with two columns/rows and that you want the value label in the second row/column. Has the benefit of not having to mess with top and bottom.

```html
<head>
<style>
.crypto-card{
display:grid;
grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr
}

.crypto-card .value-label{
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: .8rem;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}
 .crypto-card .value{
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 100;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="crypto-card">
<div class="value">Ethereum classic</div>
        <div class="value-label"><span class="title">15.29 TH/s</span></div>
</div>
</body>
```